# Nailing tongue and groove cedar trim in a 4 inch space

Tags: trim

We have a tongue and groove cedar ceiling to install; however, the problem is we have a lower coffer two feet inside the upper ceiling to be covered in the cedar. The space we have to nail into is 4.25 inches. Can anyone help us?

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the situation?

Comment: If you are having trouble getting a hammer in there to nail, try pre-dilling holes and using screws, or a palm type air nailer. Not quite sure what the question is here.

Comment: Right-angle drill with screws might also help.